# Indexes in an array of closed intervals of those containing a given number

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a generic way of finding when a given number is contained in intervals among an array of closed intervals (including the end points), and reporting the indexes of those intervals. I obtained this:

```
sets (not a partition): [[0,8], [6,15], [14,25]]
findInSets : 7 -> [0, 1]
findInSets : 30 -> []
```

```js
// findInSets :: number -> array-{indexes}
const isInRange = (x = 0, [a, b] = [0, 1]) => ([a, b] = [a, b].sort((a, b) => a > b)) && (x >= a && x <= b),
  findInSets = (x = 0, sets = [
    [0, 1]
  ]) => sets.map((subset, index) => (isInRange(x, subset)) ? index : -1).filter(index => index > -1);

console.log(
  findInSets(7, [
    [8, 0],
    [6, 15],
    [14, 25],
    [99, 0]
  ])
);
```

With some `es6` magic, can it be (even) neater? *`es6` is so much fun!*

Comment: You can try `Array.reduce` instead of `.map`+`.filter`. Also not sure if this is the right place for *can it be (even) neater*?

Comment: If you really mean *set*, why care about indices? sets are inherently unordered. You could actually use the es6 `Set` instead of arrays.

Comment: `const contains = x => ([a,b]) => x >= a && x <= b || x >= b && x <= a;
const findInSets = (x, sets) => sets.filter(contains(x)).map(set => sets.indexOf(set));`

Comment: @Touffy I was thinking in a *mathematic* way. I meant *intervals* (which are a kind of sets). Morning coffee...
@Thomas Very interesting pattern. I was looking for a way I could use `Array.prototype.findIndex()` but I did not think about `Array.prototype.indexOf()`.

Comment: I think your question would be vastly more understandable if, now that you've had your morning coffee, you used the word "interval" in it. The other useful word here is "array", and you can finally describe your structure as an array of intervals, and to be even more helpful, tell us if the intervals include either end (is 8 contained in `[0,8]` ?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your contributions, I made [some benchmarks (http://jsben.ch/#/dszDn)](http://jsben.ch/#/dszDn). Built upon Thomas (fastest + functional) and Nina Scholz (spread op, cool but *very ineffective*), I got this function:

```js
const findInIntervals = (x, intvArr) => intvArr
                                        .filter(
                                          (intv) => Math.min(...intv) <= x && x <= Math.max(...intv)
                                        ).map(intv => intvArr.indexOf(intv));
```

*Note on 2017/04:* Avoid spread operators and use Thomas's version if you are looking for speed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Math.min` and `Math.max` without sorting the inner arrays and map the index if found and filter only found indices.

```js
var findInSets = (value, array) =>
        array.
            map((a, i) =>
                Math.min(...a) <= value && value <= Math.max(...a) ? i : -1).
            filter(a => a + 1);

console.log(findInSets(7, [[8, 0], [6, 15], [14, 25], [99, 0]]));
```

Comment: It looks like @Thomas version is faster than your and mine. I guess it is because he is filtering *before* mapping. Thanks for the spread element idea (even if it is very slow)!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `reduce` to get the required indexes.

```js
function findInSets(x, sets){
  return sets.reduce((ret, set, index) => {
     if(x >= Math.min.apply(Math, set) && x <= Math.max.apply(Math, set)){
          ret.push(index)
     }
     return ret;
 }, []);
}


console.log(
  findInSets(7, [
    [8, 0],
    [6, 15],
    [14, 25],
    [99, 0]
  ])
);
```

Although this works, I'm not sure how efficient it is.

Comment: I like the reduce (= map + filter, here) but *why* bothering with the `Function.prototype.apply()`?

Comment: @hsolatges  Instinct, I'm not that used to the `spread syntax` `...iterableObject`.